# SQL Server Pivot Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm having a difficult time with Pivot in SQL Server.

My table has the following data:

| ID | Date | STEP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 2/2/2022 | 2 |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 1 |
| 2 | 3/3/2022 | 2 |

What I need is the following result:

| ID | Step_1 | Step_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 2/2/2022 |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | 3/3/2022 |

Is there any way to use `PIVOT` in this problem? Or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: how to pivot the each step to the column and the result of each step is in date column

Comment: `a difficult time with Pivot` have you tried something? Have you actually tried to use the PIVOT clause or do you refer to pivoting in general? In SQL (the language) `PIVOT` requires and aggregate method for the value fields. If there's no chance of more than two date values for an ID and Step combination, MIN or MAX would do. If there can be more than one value, you'll have to decide what you want.

Comment: @MarchelGunawanDwiSteya check Tim Biegeleisen's answer. PIVOT is complicated so it's often better (and sometimes faster) to use a simpler solution. And that includes the `CASE` logic used before the PIVOT clause was introduced. Quite often, it's less code to use `MAX(CASE` than write a full PIVOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there would only ever be 2 steps *and* the dates increase with step number, then you may use a simple `GROUP BY` query here:

```sql
SELECT ID, MIN(Date) AS Step_1, MAX(Date) AS Step_2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Otherwise, for a more robust query, use formal pivoting logic:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP = 1 THEN Date END) AS Step_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP = 2 THEN Date END) AS Step_2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: People (including MVPs) have been wondering why `PIVOT` exists since it was introduced. Do you remember why it was introduced? Looking back I think it was only because Oracle had it and at the time (2005). SQL Server could go after Oracle but not DB2, so they added more Oracle-y functions. Probably same reason SQL Server got more MySQL-y features before it went cloud-y.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To add to what you said, it is my understanding that `PIVOT` won't necessarily outperform the old school `GROUP BY` version in my answer.  Plus, I find `PIVOT` hard to read.

Comment: I wonder if there's any StackExchange site where people can ask `Why was PIVOT added` or `How come PostgreSQL doesn't have temporal tables, when Stonebraker proposed the very first temporal model? Still cross it got rejected after 20 years?`. Could get hot though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos See [codinghistory.se], oh sorry not created yet. `PIVOT` and `GROUP BY` perform exactly the same, assuming the `PIVOT` is grouping by the same columns. If you look at the execution plan you will see it compiles down into a `GROUP BY` and `MAX(CASE` anyway

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use Tim Biegeleisen's answer unless you have a very good reason. The `PIVOT` clause takes almost as much code as the `MAX(CASE....)` version but is harder to write and read.

And I can never remember the syntax. I always have to look it up.

Using `PIVOT`, you need to

```
SELECT ID,
       [1] as Step_1, 
       [2] as Step_2
FROM  
(
  SELECT ID,Date,Step
  FROM yourTable
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(Date)  
  FOR Step IN ([1], [2])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

In SQL you can't have an arbitrary number of columns, or multiple values per column. The `PIVOT` clause identifies the `Step` values that become columns and the aggregate function used to reduce potentially multiple "cell" values into a single one.

Compare this with this equivalent:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP = 1 THEN Date END) AS Step_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP = 2 THEN Date END) AS Step_2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Which one is clearer?

What if you decide to use *different* aggregate functions per step?

```
SELECT ID,
       MIN(CASE WHEN STEP = 1 THEN Date END) AS Step_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STEP = 2 THEN Date END) AS Step_2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```